# getting Id_token using Azure AD Authentication Library(ADAL in angular 5), but how to get access token from Id_token?

Tags: javascript, angular, azure, adal

I am using adal service in angular 5 project for Microsoft auth2.0 authentication.
I am getting id_token by

*this.adalService.getCachedToken(this.secretService.adalConfig.clientId);*

But I need Accesstoken for further token verification.

I tried https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me api
but got *Access token validation failure* error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be

```
this.adalService.acquireToken("https://graph.microsoft.com", (error, token) => {
    // token has the Access Token
});
```

If you use the `$httpProvider` and `requireADLogin`, then you should automagically have an access token requested and attached for that destination:

```
$routeProvider.when("/forecast", {
    controller: "forecastController",
    templateUrl: "/views/forecast.html",
    requireADLogin: true
});
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-angular